# Does anyone know how long it takes an ELB to scale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am currently working on a project where I need the ELB to scale on demand. I am currently trying to do this by pre-warming the server with a load tester, however, it never seems to catch up to the load that is being thrown at it. Ideally I want to just be able to throw a load at it and x minutes later be able to handle said traffic.

Comment: You need to talk to AWS Support people to pre-warm your ELB.: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/best-practices-in-evaluating-elastic-load-balancing/#pre-warming

Comment: I realize you can do it that way, however each of my clients needs to do this on demand. Is there any way to force it without contacting amazon?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You may get a better answer if you talk to them. They are amazing people.

Comment: I think the documentation is clear. Either pre-warm by AWS support, or control the load so that it will not increase no more than 50 percent over a five-minute interval. So there is no on-demand option to control the scaling.

Comment: Also, ELB means CLB (Classic)? ALB runs on EC2 and NLB does not. So if it is NLB, I wonder if pre-warm option exists and would check with AWS.

Comment: @mon NLB does not need to scale.  It's a phantom device provided by something called AWS Hyperplane that's integrated with VPC networking.  [*"NLB is optimized to handle sudden and volatile traffic patterns while using a single static IP address per Availability Zone."*](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-network-load-balancer-effortless-scaling-to-millions-of-requests-per-second/)

Comment: @Dylan *"it never seems to catch up to the load that is being thrown at it"* What is "it" -- the balancer?  How do you know that it is the thing that can't handle the load? What behavior do you see?  Also, are you correctly testing it?  ALB and ELB hostnames resolve to 1 IP address per AZ initially, and more IP addresses are added as it scales out and/or up. If you are not continuously re-resolving that hostname and connecting to all of the IP addresses it resolves to while load testing, then you're only testing one node of the balancer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am always monitoring my kubernetes cluster... CPU and ram usage were under 5% when I was doing load tests on the server. I am certain it was the CLB... The problem with using an NLB is that it only handles TCP which doesn't work for my service. As for connection to the ELB - I have everything automatically put onto one of the subdomains of my service. When testing, I am using said domain which should route to all IP addresses.

Comment: I am going to talk to an AWS rep and see what they think... If I MUST contact support to pre-warm I will have to hire an employee to do this upon requests for clients - or, I will have to find a way to pre-warm the ELB manually by giving it about 60% load for 5 minute intervals until I get to a certain scale. It would be a lot of trial and error because i'm not to clear on how they scale these but i'm sure I can make it work

Comment: *"I am using said domain which should route to all IP addresses."*  Not necessarily, if your benchmarking software looks up the address at the beginning of the benchmarking process.  Verify what IP(s) it's actually connecting to, using netstat.